# I mistakenly hid my calendar how to recover

Tags: vba, outlook

I ran the following script to hide folders in outlook and I mistakenly hide my calendar

```
Option Explicit
 
Public Sub HideFolders()

Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
Dim PropName, Value, FolderType As String

PropName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10F4000B"
Value = True
 
Set oFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
Set oPA = oFolder.PropertyAccessor

oPA.SetProperty PropName, Value
 
Set oFolder = Nothing
Set oPA = Nothing
End Sub
```

I then tried the following script to recover my outlook calendar but it did not work

```
Option Explicit
 
Public Sub FindFolders()

Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
Dim PropName, Value, FolderType As String

PropName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10F4000B"
Value = False
 
Set oFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
Set oPA = oFolder.PropertyAccessor

oPA.SetProperty PropName, Value
 
Set oFolder = Nothing
Set oPA = Nothing
End Sub
```

any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix a problem like that without a script using [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IMsgStore button, click "Open Folder", select the folder to open, double click the `PR_ATTR_HIDDEN` property to edit.